# Why does Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error occur when I use ajax, but not when I use rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, access-control

So I tried getting a response (tried xml, json and jsonp) from [career builder's api](http://api.careerbuilder.com/) using AJAX, however I always get the “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” Error. But, when I tried, [icodeya's tutorial](http://www.icodeya.com/2013/10/ruby-on-rails-json-requests-tutorial.html) and took a response from a controller, the error disappeared and I was able to get a response. Why is that?

Comment: You need to understand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

Only requests from the browser are subject to same origin policy. Server to server communication is not.